# start/stop android service based on call events

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

how can i start/stop a specific service based on the following:

1. user A call user B ( the trigger is user B answer the phone and service stopped when call is ended )
2. user B call user A ( the trigger is user A answer the phone and service stopped when call is ended )

i want to calculate the call duration of the call and store the result in database.

regards

Answer (score 0):

The calculation of the call duration is already done for you. Use the `CallLog` content provider, please.

Even if for some strange reason using the official call log is not what you want, you do not need a service. Set up a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` for `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` and store the start/stop times in the database. Do not have a `Service` hanging out in memory for the sole purpose of watching time tick by.

But, please, just use the `CallLog`, since the OS is doing this work for you, and you don't waste the user's battery doing duplicate work.